# Dart class inheritance: How to assign all proprieties of parent class to child child

Tags: inheritance, dart

I have two classes: `Person` and `Student`. `Student` extends `Person`. When a `Person` signs up as a `Student`, the new proprieties of `Student` are attributed. I want to pass all the proprities of Person to Student. To do that I created a custom constructor: `Student.fromPerson(Person person)`  However, the class Person have so many proprieties and when developers add a propriety to Person, they also have to update this contructor in Student.  Is there a way to attribute automatically proprities of person to its superclass since it is the same type without writing:  `: super(fname: person.fname, lname: person.lname);` and listing all the proprieties?

```
class Person {
  String fname;
  String lname;

  Person({this.fname, this.lname});
}

class Student extends Person {
  String major;
  String year;

  Student({this.major, this.year, String fname, String lname})
      : super(fname: fname, lname: lname);

  Student.fromPerson(Person person, {this.major, this.year})
      : super(fname: person.fname, lname: person.lname); // <- is there a better way

}

void main() {
  Person person = Person(fname: "Lina", lname: "Dosse");
    Student student = Student.fromPerson(person, major: 'CS', year: '2015');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no single approach that will work everywhere. On the VM you *could* use `dart:mirrors` to reflect the fields of `Person`, but this won't work on the web or in flutter. You could also use codegen to generate the boilerplate code that copies over fields but I'm not aware of any existing builders that do this so you'd need to implement it yourself. (See https://github.com/dart-lang/build/tree/master/docs if you want to try this route).

A better approach may be to change the model. Instead of modeling it with `Student` *is* a `Person`, you could try `Student` *has* a `Person`.

```
class Student {
    Person person;
    String major;
    String year;

    Student({this.person, this.major, this.year});
}
```